# email.header not handling Finnish characters?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, utf, python-unicode

A certain Python API returns `u'J\xe4rvenp\xe4\xe4'` for the finish word Järvenpää.

where \xe4 == ä

I then am calling email.header to add this field to a header to be printed.

`email.header` falls over when it tries to decode the umlaut:

```
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/email/header.py", line 73, in decode_header
    header = str(header)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe4' in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I've tried a couple of things:

- Addding `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`
  to the top of header.py
- Calling `unicode()` on the Finnish string before passing it to email.header
- Calling `.encode('utf-8')` on the Finnish string before passing it to email.header

None have solved the problem. What I am doing wrong? I'd imagine that a solution won't involve modifying `header.py` (a core Python module).

**Python version: 2.7.10**

**UPDATE:**

Header() is not being instantiated directly. Rather I'm callind the decode_header() function on the string:

```
email.Header.decode_header(theString)
```

It seems now that simply extend this thus:

```
email.Header.decode_header(theString.encode('utf-8'))
```

solves the problem

Comment: How are you using the `email` module to add the header? Please include your code in the question, ideally a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @LukasGraf see my UPDATE. Would you trust this solution as a reliable one? Or would you suggest something different?

Comment: Wait - are you trying to *create* a header (sending email) or *parse* a header (reading email)?

Comment: `decode_header` is a helper function for turning an [RFC 2047](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2047.txt) *email header* into a Python string by decoding it into a list of `(decoded_string, charset)` tuples. Can you please update your question with a complete example for what you're trying to do (not just snippets)?

Comment: @LukasGraf a clearer and more thorough problem description here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30907708/how-to-get-email-header-decode-header-to-work-with-non-ascii-characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to have the `email.header` module handle encoding for you and create a proper header, you have to create an instance of [`email.header.Header`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.header.html#email.header.Header) with your string and the charset it should be encoded in:

```
>>> h = Header(text, charset)
```

For example:

```
>>> t = u'J\xe4rvenp\xe4\xe4'
>>> print t
Järvenpää
>>> from email.header import Header
>>> h = Header(t, 'utf-8')
>>> h
<email.header.Header instance at 0x7fc2636e7950>
>>> print h
=?utf-8?b?SsOkcnZlbnDDpMOk?=
>>> h = Header(t, 'iso-8859-1')
>>> print h
=?iso-8859-1?q?J=E4rvenp=E4=E4?=
```

The string can be either a **unicode** string or a **byte string**.

- If you use a unicode string, the `charset` will only affect what encoding the header is *encoded* with.
- If you use a byte string, the `charset` will both determine what encoding the byte string is assumed to be in, and what encoding will be used to encode the header. If the byte string you provide can't be decoded with that `charset`, an exception will be raised.

Answer (score -1):

AFAIK, str() deals with ascii that's why you get an error. If your string is unicode you should do `header = unicode(header)`, if not it should be decoded first.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

header = unicode("Järvenpää".decode('UTF-8'))
print header
```

Output

```
Järvenpää
```

Comment: `"bytestring".decode(charset)` will already return a `unicode` instance - that additional `unicode()` call doesn't do anything at all. And if it were (when you do `unicode(bytestring)` for example), it will always try to implicitly decode `bytestring` with the system default encoding, which is `ascii` in Python 2.x - so it will fail for anything that isn't ASCII. So never use `unicode(bytestring)` please.

Comment: You wish. Normal encoding for Finnish is ISO-8859-15. That's why I gave an example. I tried that string in my terminal.

Comment: There is no such thing as "normal encoding for Finnish" - if you're dealing with byte strings, you always have to know the encoding that was used. The problem with your answer is that you completely ignore the fact that the question is about *email headers*, and that you state things that are simply wrong.

Comment: Yeah, right. The problem with your answer is that you ignore the OP's code where "header = str(header)"

Comment: That is not the OP's code, that's in the standard library's `email/header.py` module.

Comment: OK, OK. You are the smartest one. I put a minus to you anyway.